# How to create SQL that uses input from a Multi-select list in MS Access

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access

I have an SQL query that creates output for a form based on a few selected inputs; start date, end date, store location, and it works fine. However, I need to change the store location selector from a single selection comboBox to a multi-selection listBox. In the former, I simply reference the comboBox field to get the data for the SQL `WHERE` clause. In the latter, there can be one or more values selected in the list box and I need the SQL to use each of these values (`OR`'ed) to get the results for the report.

I have not tried this, but I am thinking I will have to run the SQL for each of the selected values, but not sure if there is a better way.

```sql
SELECT
    Store.District
  , Store.GM_name
  , Store.Location
  , YEAR(Sales.Date_)                                  AS TheYear
  , SUM(Sales.[Total Sales])                           AS SumTotalSales
  , SUM(Sales.[Cust Count])                            AS SumCustCount
  , SUM(Sales.[Total Sales])/SUM([Sales].[Cust Count]) AS AverageTicket
  , SUM(Sales.Payroll)                                 AS SumPayroll
  , SUM(Sales.[Payroll])/SUM([Sales].[Total Sales])    AS PayrollPercent
  , SUM(Sales.[Bonus Pay])                             AS SumBonusPay
  , SUM(Sales.[Holiday Pay])                           AS SumHolidayPay
  , SUM(Sales.[Vacation Pay])                          AS SumVacationPay
  , SUM(Sales.[Sicktime Pay])                          AS SumSicktimePay
  , SUM(Sales.[Cpl Cost])                              AS SumCplCost
  , SUM(Sales.[Cpl Cost])      /SUM([Sales].[Total Sales])   AS CPLCostPct
  , SUM(Sales.[Holiday Pay])   /SUM(Sales.[Total Sales])     AS HolidayPayrollPercent
  , SUM(Sales.[Bonus Pay])     /SUM(Sales.[Total Sales])     AS BonusPayrollPercent
  , SUM([Sales].[Vacation Pay])/SUM([Sales].[Total Sales])   AS VacPayrollPercent
  , SUM([Sales].[Sicktime Pay])/SUM([Sales].[Total Sales])   AS SicktimePayrollPercent
  , SUM(Sales.[Total Food Cost])                             AS SumTotalFoodCost
  , SUM(Sales.[Total Food Cost])/SUM([Sales].[Total Sales])  AS TotalFoodCostPct
  , SUM(Sales.[NGSS Percent])                                AS SumNGSSPercent
  , SUM(Sales.[TA Total Percent])                            AS SumTATotalPercent
  , SUM([Sales.Manager Pay])                                 AS SumManagersPay
  , SUM(Sales.[Manager Pay])/SUM([Sales].[Total Sales])      AS ManagerPayrollPct
  , SUM(Sales.[Training Pay])                                AS SumTrainingPay
  , SUM(Sales.[Training Pay])/SUM([Sales].[Total Sales])     AS TrainingPayrollPct
FROM
    Store
    INNER JOIN
        Sales
    ON
        Store.ID = Sales.Store_ID
    --> This WHERE is where the single store location is retrieved,
     --> but need to get all selected locations on the SelectedStore
    --> control and OR these results
WHERE
    (
        (
            (
                Store.Location
            )
            =[Forms]![Startup]![SelectedStore].[value]
        )
        AND
        (
            (
                Sales.Date_
            )
            BETWEEN [Forms]![Startup]![StartDateToView] AND [Forms]![Startup]![EndDateToView]
            OR
            (
                Sales.Date_
            )
            BETWEEN DATEADD("yyyy",-1,[Forms]![Startup]![StartDateToView]) AND DATEADD("yyyy",-1,[Forms]![Startup]![EndDateToView])
        )
    )
GROUP BY
    Store.District
  , Store.GM_name
  , Store.Location
  , YEAR(Sales.Date_);
```

Comment: [How to fomat sql](https://www.sqlinform.com/online-sql-formatter/)."I have not tried this, but I am thinking I will have to run the SQL for each of the selected values" why not? Asking the web on question title (copy&paste), should be mandatory!

Answer (score 0):

If you were constructing this query in VBA, it would be relatively trivial to construct a query that would `OR` against the selected values. But presumably this is for a saved query, or a query saved in a property that expects SQL; and you don't want to rewrite the SQL each time the selection in the listbox is changed.

I can think of two possibilities:

- If you can use VBA, you could write a function that takes a value and the listbox. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to pass in the listbox directly -- it's assuming I want the listbox value, and not the listbox itself -- but passing in the names of the form and listbox works:

  ```vb
  Function InListbox(value As Variant, formName As String, listboxName As String) As Boolean
      Dim lb As ListBox
      Set lb = Forms(formName)(listboxName)

      Dim index As Variant
      For Each index In lb.ItemsSelected
          If lb.Column(0, index) = value Then
              InListbox = True
              Exit Function
          End If
      Next
  End Function
  ```

  You can then use the function in your SQL, like this:

  ```sql
  SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.Text
  FROM Table1
  WHERE InListbox(Table1.Text, "Form1", "List0")
  ```
- Alternatively, you could handle selection changes on the listbox, writing the selected values into a dedicated table (and clearing unselected values); you could then join your query on that table.

  This method has a downside (as ComputerVersteher notes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57891886/how-to-create-sql-that-uses-input-from-a-multi-select-list-in-ms-access/57893438?noredirect=1#comment102214907_57895010)). When you delete records in an Access database, Access doesn't reuse the space left behind; added records will increase the size of the database. You therefore need to compact the database every so often, to release this empty space.

Comment: Yes, I can use VBA. I have it coded to find the values in the listbox (and put them in a text box), but where I am getting confused is in trying to use option one you mentioned. How do I use a function within a query?

Comment: @Rich Just like any other function. :) If you have a function named `Function MyFunction(lb As Variant) As Boolean`, you can call it within SQL as `MyFunction(Forms!Form1!MyListbox)`. I'll try to provide some sample code shortly.

Comment: @Rich I've updated my answer with some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input Zev. I used the second method by first creating and filling a temp table with the selections. Then I used a second INNER JOIN (prior to the first one) that joined the store.location with the tempTable.location to narrow down the results.

Comment: Be aware that access tables need compacting after deletions to reduce its size.